React Native Expo app says "Custom Layout View" in Android build only
after I start the app, the splash screen is followed by a white screen saying "Custom Layout View" but only using Android. The expected behaviour is to show the actual first screen of the app. The problem does not appear on ios at all and the problem does also not appear in android expo go. It is only in android build
I checked the app.json and my router structure. I use a _layout file in app folder an another one in (tabs) folder.
EDIT:
Caused by "expo-web-view" library. Issue was gone after I uninstalled it

Caused by "expo-web-view" library. Issue was gone after I uninstalled it
